# How to share video in Twitter using Twitter kit 3 in the android?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-share

**After fabric removal , now Twitter kit 3 is used in the android**

**Case :**

- I need share the text , image and video without opening the `Twitter Composer`
- I am sharing the text , image and the video using twitter kit 3 by using the method `StatusesService`
- So i can share the text by using below code :

  ```
  final TwitterSession session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
  StatusesService statusesService = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient(session).getStatusesService();
  statusesService.update("Click this link "+getShareLink(),null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null).enqueue(new Callback<Tweet>() {
      @Override
      public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {
          Toast.makeText(context,"Tweet success ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Log.e(TAG,"Twitter "+ result.data.toString());
      }

      @Override
      public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
          Toast.makeText(context,"Tweet failure ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Log.e(TAG,"Twitter "+ exception.getMessage());
      }
  });
  ```
- For image upload we can use `MediaService` and for uploading it we can use `MediaService.upload()` method , but in the `MediaService`**they are only prompt the images to upload** and i also checked their docs .
- And now **How to share Video in the Twitter kit 3 using `StatuesServices` or any other method ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The native video upload support is only available with [iOS](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/compose-tweets) (See attachment section)

2) *Quick Bad workaround*  You can convert video to gif and upload it.

3) *Proper solution*:

You can [extend](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/access-rest-api#extensions) the kit, and use [the media/uploads endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/overview).

See this to make a [post](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload) request.

Comment: yes it is correct  , i have done it through twitter4j but unfortunately it does not work in twitter sdk by extending it because INIT , APPEND works , when checking the STATUS before FINALIZE step ,  it throws error @Optional

Comment: What is the error. Can you share your json payload and response?

Comment: u have done it by extending the twitter kit in the android ?

Comment: To be fair no. But i have seen it being extended and achieved, that too without using Composer Api.

Comment: Yes @optional but it has issues

Comment: Way to go. Cheers @KoVartthan

Answer (score 0):

It's working on tweet-composer:3.3.0.

I simply added the video Uri to the place where we normally add the image Uri.
It worked unexpectedly.

```
private void shareVideoViaTwitter(File file) {
    try {
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.civ.petcam.fileprovider", file);

        context.startActivity(new TweetComposer.Builder(context)
                .text("This video is made with PetCamera")
                .url(new URL("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.civ.petcam"))
                .image(uri).createIntent().setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

        onVideoShareCompleteListener.onVideoShareComplete("twitter");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```